# Does ASCII have a header or footer or anything similar?

Tags: byte, ascii

I'm working through a problem in Programming Pearls -- specifically, the implementation of a program which sorts a file containing, at most, 10,000,000 integers, each of which is 7 digits long (Column 1, Problem 3).

The problem has some very strict constraints when it comes to memory, so I'm considering reading and writing the integers in ASCII -- 7 bytes at a time. I need to know if ASCII has any headers or footers or anything similar that I should be considering  (I'm putting everything on 1 line without any separators, so new lines aren't an issue).

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem right, but I think a numerical encoding would be smarter. You can encode every 7 digit decimal number with 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCII is a fixed width encoding and only concerns itself with byte<->character mapping. There are no headers or footers in it.

On *nix you should be able to view your bytes using `od` (eg `$ od -h filename` to print hex byte representations).

Answer (score 2):

No, text files only contain the bytes of the text nothing more nothing less.